# What are the implications of adding ISO 15288 after ISO 12207?

Tags: standards, hardware

This question is aimed at QA people who have already adopted ISO 12207.

Do any of you have experience with ISO 15288 as well?

How does the act of adopting 15288 *after* starting with 12207 affect existing process documents?

Can you leave your 12207 software-specific process documents as is, and only introduce non-software process documents as required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ISO 15288 covers the System lifecycle, while ISO 12207 covers the Software lifecycle. As of 2008, [the two are "harmonized for concurrent use"](http://www.acq.osd.mil/se/apr/apr-4.html). For instance, 12207 can be used "[either alone or in conjunction with ... 15288](http://www.jtc1-sc7.org/)"

In a bit more detail, what this means is that 15288 covers all aspects of developing a system, where examples of system components are hardware, software, people, or resources. When a system component is software, the processes described in 12207 (should) take over.

So, to answer your question, your 12207 software-specific process documents should only need to change *where they cover the interfaces between software and non-software components*. This might include such things as:

- documenting software dependencies on hardware
- ensuring that your organization has a way to provide personnel with any training needed to use the software
- describing the impact of provision, transportation, or maintenance of resources controlling, or controlled by, the software

... and so on.